# All monic polynomials of degree $2$ in $\Bbb F_3[x]$ (there should be nine of them)

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> A polynomial of degree $n$ is *monic* iff $a_n=1$

I have tried to write down all monic polynomials of degree $2$ in $\Bbb F_3[x]$ like this:

> \begin{align}\\
> & x^2 && x^2+1 && x^2-1\\
> & x^2+x && x^2-x && x^2+x+1 \\
> & x^2+x-1 && x^2-x-1 && x^2-x+1 \\
> \end{align}

Is this correct?

I have looked at these questions from before, but I don't know if I have understood it correctly.

[Find the monic irreducible polynomials of degree 2 in $F_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148368/find-the-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-2-in-f-3)

[Irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb F_3[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800806/irreducible-polynomials-in-mathbb-f-3x)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: There are 9 polynomials but your list is not fully correct. $x^2+1$ appears twice and $x^2+x+1$ is missing.